# How can I change the language of the UI of Google maps to English?

Tags: google-maps, localization

- My operating system language is English US.
- My regional settings in operating system are English US
- My browser settings are in English US. Three different browsers: Google Chrome, Opera, Firefox.
- My Google account settings are set to language English US. All products.
- My android phone has the language set to English US. All Google apps appear on English US.
- I clear my browsers settings, cookies, cache, storage, session storage.
- I try incognito, non-incognito window
- I try to login with my Google account
- I try not login without any account

Still, if I type maps.google.com, it appears in a language that is not English US. I can change the language of the UI to another language using the button in the left menu. When I finish using the page and reload it, it appears in a language that is not English US.

Anyone has a clue how can I change the language of Google maps to English?

Answer (score 0):

May be you are using an firewall or antivirus or (A virus in system) which using as a proxy to that region to spy on you.

Or

Open google.com set it to english.

or

set your browser default language to english.